# How to get Mapbox Geocoder result place/country text names into a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mapbox-gl-js

When the Mapbox geocoder returns a search result, I need to get the city(place name) and country name text and put them into a text field on the web page.

This returns the data to the console.

```
<script>
geocoder.on('results', function(results) {
   console.log(results);
})
</script>
```

A geocoder search for New york returns this GeoJSON object data. I need to get the country text data when a search result is returned and update a text field on the web page with the country name text.

```
<script>
features: Array(5)
0:
bbox: (4) [-74.2590879797556, 40.477399, -73.7008392055224, 40.917576401307]
center: (2) [-73.9808, 40.7648]
context: Array(2)
0: {id: "region.14044236392855570", short_code: "US-NY", wikidata: "Q1384", text_en-GB: "New York", language_en-GB: "en", …}
1:
id: "country.9053006287256050"
language: "en"
language_en-GB: "en"
short_code: "us"
text: "United States of America"
text_en-GB: "United States of America"
wikidata: "Q30"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: Array(2)}
id: "place.15278078705964500"
language: "en"
language_en-GB: "en"
matching_place_name: "New York, New York, United States of America"
matching_text: "New York"
place_name: "New York City, New York, United States of America"
place_name_en-GB: "New York City, New York, United States of America"
place_type: ["place"]
properties: {wikidata: "Q60"}
relevance: 1
text: "New York City"
text_en-GB: "New York City"
type: "Feature"
__proto__: Object
</script>
```

The below code updates the text field. However, not with the actual data from the above data. How do I query/access the actual result data after every search to update the text field?

```
<script>
//listen for a search result
document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--input').addEventListener('change', titleTest);

function titleTest() {

var countryName = {
  id: "country.9053006287256050",
  language: "en",
  language_enGB: "en",
  short_code: "us",
  text: "United States of America",
  text_enGB: "United States of America",
  wikidata: "Q30"
}

  //update the input field
document.getElementById('titleinput').value = countryName.text.toUpperCase(); 
  //add to map
document.getElementById("map_title").innerHTML = countryName.text.toUpperCase();

</script>
```

The below line returns the value for 'place_name: "New York City, New York, United States of America"'

```
<script>
 let str = document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--input').value;
</script>
```

Let's try it in the script below..

```
<script>
// listen for a search
document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--input').addEventListener('change', updateTitle);

function updateTitle() {

 //get the text value for place
 let str = document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder--input').value;

 //split the string
 let countryName = str.split(", ");

 //loop over array items  
 for(var i = 0; i < countryName.length; i++)
{
   console.log(countryName[i]);
}

  //update the input field
  document.getElementById('titleinput').value = countryName[1].toUpperCase();
 //add to map
  document.getElementById("map_title").innerHTML = countryName[1].toUpperCase();
</script>
```

The above code gets me the mapbox suggestion [place_name] as a string ("New York City, New York, United States of America"), which I then split to a list, and iterate over. It works well for place/city as this array position is always first [0]. However, it doesn't work well for getting the country name, which isn't always in the same position in the string, or the list. For example, if I set the countryName array value to [1] and search for 'London', the second item is 'Greater London', 'England' was [2] and 'United Kingdom' was [3], whereas if I search for 'Paris', [1] gives me 'France'.

I need to get the country name text when the geocoder returns a result so I can add it to the text field. How do I get the country name text from the object after every search result? Does anyone know?

Comment: From what I can see obj.place_name returns a list of names. Have you tried iterating over that list?

Comment: If I am wrong and it is returning the string "New York City, New York, United States" Then you can turn that string into a list by performing a split:

listOfNames = obj.place_name.split(", ")

Comment: That would work, but I'm not getting the real place_name value from the json. How do I get the "New York City, New York, United States" text from the json into my function to add to the text field?

Comment: I can get the string "New York City, New York, United States" using some jQuery (see updated question). I could use .split() to get the country name. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I personally would drop the text "United States" and pull the country from elsewhere from the Josn array. Otherwise you can just split it like I suggested and put each part of the object where you need it.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know how to get the country value from the json. How do I split the string with the above jQuery? where do I add the .split(", ") into the function? I only need the first and last items in the string as these are usually the city/country values.

Comment: ok give me a sec\

Answer (score 3):

```
  geocoder.on("result", (e) => {
    function getAddressByType(value, index, array) {
      if (value.id.match(/country.*/)) {
       console.log(value.text)
      } else if (value.id.match(/region.*/)) {
       console.log(value.text)
      } else if (value.id.match(/postcode.*/)) {
       console.log(value.text)
      } else if (value.id.match(/district.*/)) {
       console.log(value.text)
      } else if (value.id.match(/place.*/)) {
          console.log(value.text)
      } else if (value.id.match(/neighborhood.*/)) {
            console.log(value.text)
      } else if (value.id.match(/address.*/)) {
            console.log(value.text)
      } else if (value.id.match(/poi.*/)) {
       console.log(value.text)
      }
    }
    e.result.context.forEach(getAddressByType);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  });
```

note : "results" and "result" return different data.
This is how I fetch all data under the context of "result" function.
I loop the e.result.context then use a function to access the object to make sure I can use all object return on that array.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that way will help you, that is how I resolved it. Note that you can do if-else-if instead of several if's as I did. You could even use switch if you wish so.

```
    geocoder.on('result', (e) => {
      for(let i=0; i < e.result.context.length; i++) {
        if(e.result.context[i].id.includes('postcode')) {
          this.form.postcode = e.result.context[i].text;
        }
        if(e.result.context[i].id.includes('locality')) {
          this.form.line_2 = e.result.context[i].text;
        }
        if(e.result.context[i].id.includes('place')) {
          this.form.city = e.result.context[i].text;
        }
        if(e.result.context[i].id.includes('district')) {
          this.form.county = e.result.context[i].text;
        }
        if(e.result.context[i].id.includes('country')) {
          this.form.country = e.result.context[i].text;
        }
      }
      // First line of address
      if(e.result.text || e.result.address) {
        this.form.line_1 = (e.result.address ? e.result.address + ' ' : '') + (e.result.text ? e.result.text : '');
      }
      // Full Address
      if(e.result.place_name) {
        this.form.full_address = e.result.place_name;
      }
      // Coordinates
      if(e.result.center) {
        this.form.longitude = e.result.center[0];
        this.form.latitude = e.result.center[1];
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the the Json object a return the string you are looking for. You can do a split function on this string to get all the values individually like so.

```
var listOfNames = obj.place_name.split(", ");
ListOfNames[0] = "New York City" 
ListOfNames[1] = "New York"
ListOfNames[2] = "United States"
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with a new solution. However, I think you were right to say you would get the country from the json as simply splitting the geocoder suggestion is unreliable. The country name is not always in the same list position, sometimes it's the second array item, sometimes the fourth. Do you know how to get the country name from the geocoder features json? Perhaps I have to make an ajax call?